Using that without prepositions

The house where Dickens wrote his later novels is now a school=The house that Dickens wrote his later novels in is now a school

Here I was able to change "where" to "that" but I had to add "in" without that it would be incorrect

It was the day when the heatwave started= it was the day that the heatwave started

My question
I don't understand why it is possible at least according to my book to switch "when" into " that" without "on". Why is it like that? Is it like one time exception and in other cases we always include the preposition?

To write novels in a house is not not grammatical but that sentence about Dickens would just not be used. Your 2) doesn't make sense. Please CHECK  your spelling and punctuation before posting.

"it was the day that the heatwave started on" would also be grammatical. I suggest you read up on relative clauses in a good English grammar book, though, because you don't seem to have much understanding of them and it's a topic that's better explained by a proper book/tutorial.

The day that to mean “the day when” is completely idiomatic. As is the even simpler the day. Likewise for year, and so forth.
Here are a few song lyrics that illustrate this:

The night they drove old Dixie down
That’ll be the day that I die
Right when I met you, the day that I met you, you turned my world around
Been lonely since the day, the day you went away
The day they knocked down the palais, my sister stood and cried
The last time I saw Paris
The night we called it a day (See the Wiktionary entry for an explanation of the expression to call it a day.)
The day the music died
The moment I wake up, before I put on my makeup
They planted a tree the year you were born
And that was the moment I knew

And we mustn’t overlook that towering masterpiece of cinematic accomplishment, The Day the Earth Stood Still.

palais, as in palace in French? :)

@Lambie - It was a dance hall they demolished. Palais de danse is a lexical borrowing from French, meaning "dance palace", that refers to purpose-built commercial dance halls which appeared in Britain and elsewhere from the 1920s onwards.

The things we do to get a rhyming lyric...

And the Palais is also a theatre in St Kilda, the Melbourne suburb, and still in use.

Whereas 'the house that' to mean 'the house where' is not. We say the house that Jack built, but the house that Jack was born  requires in.

Just think 'that' can be used instead of 'where, when, why'.

The last time that I saw her, she was quite well.


It was snowing the day that he started.


This is the reason that he came.


Nobody likes the way (that) you behave.


the last time (that) I saw her


That’s the reason (that) I came to see you.


Things like that are apt to occur anywhere (that) people gather.


That is the way (that) he took me in. (take in=deceive)

and remember 'that' can be omitted in many cases, espcially the way (that)
Your question is why 'that' is possible without presposition.

The house that I vistied yesterday is for sale now.

no preposition here as you said. This that is diffrent from the usages above because this that(relative pronoun) is an object of the verb 'vistied' and not a relative adverb(when,where,why) usage.
